# Running time analysis, three inner for loops

Tags: performance, algorithm, analysis, pseudocode

This is my first question and I'm pretty sure that I will receive also my first answer :P

I have to make an asymptotic analysis of an algorithm that from an array `A[1...n]` compute a matrix `M[n][n]` which contains for each `M[i][j]` a value given by:

```
M[i][j] = (A[i] + ... + A[j])/(j-i+1), if i<=j
```

and

```
M[i][j] = 0, if i>j
```

```
for i=1 to N do                [N]
   for j=1 to N do             [N]
    if(i<=j)                   [cost]
      start=i                  [cost]
      end=j                    [cost]
      sum=0                    [cost]
      for a=start to end do    [??]
         sum += A[a]           [cost]
      M[i][j]=sum/(j-i+1       [cost]
    else                       [cost]
      M[i][j]=0                [cost]
```

Considering that giving the first two for loop I have to expect at least a running time of O(n^2), with the third inner for loop I will get something like O(N*N*[??]).
The third for loop executes everytime j-i+1 operations and only for i<=j.
The matrix will have the first row filled with the computed average, the second the first element equal to 0 and then the computed averages...

The final matrix will result almost half filled(but not N/2) So the value for the third loop is not [N/2]

How can I compute the running time for the innermost For and also the running time for the whole algorithm?

Comment: To me, it still looks like (roughly) N/2 for the inner-most loop.

Comment: Yes, but the whole matrix can still be built in O(N^2) time by eliminating the third loop (and keeping a running sum of the A[i]...A[j]).

Comment: In this case I can say that the running time is O(N^3)? It is an acceptable estimation for an algorithm analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to just calculate the number of times the inner loop statement gets executed.

You loop over i from 1 to N. Now you will only do the inner loop (with the sum) when j is larger than or equal to N so j loops from i to N. The inner most loop then consists of j-i additions. In all you get (in maple syntax)

```
sum(sum(j-i,j=i..N), i=1..N)= 1/6*N^3-1/6*N
```

You then need to take into account the assignment of M[i][j] which is done N^2 times.

The previous was the total amount of instructions. However, if you're just looking for the overal complexity then you should just see that the inner loop is dependent on N which gives you O(N^3) overall complexity.

Do note that the code could avoid the inner loop complexity by storing the A[i] sums from the start and don't try to recalculate them every time

Comment: Small typo: -1/6*N^3 should be 1/6*N^3.